# Database size increase after restoring

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2013, database-migration, sharepoint-2016

Recently my team did a sharepoint migration from 2013 to 2016. We used the Attach and Detach method for the database from SQL Server 2008r2 to SQL Server 2012. It was successful however the database size has increased by about 3 times.

When i take a look at the database files there is duplicated files. In 2008 database there is 2 files but in 2013 there is 6 files causing the increase of 3 times.The 2 files duplicated by 3 so now i have 6 files.

I would like to have an explanation. Is there anyone who know what cause the file to duplicate or a link to an article regarding this?

In addition i would also like to know how can i resize the database size back to how i was? Meaning i would like it to be back to its original size.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is an explanation for size increase ,but not for this `n 2008 database there is one 2 files but in 2013 there is 6 files `

Comment: Please update your post with the results of select *
from sys.database_files executed on both servers. Then, did I understand well, you detached your db, copy only 2 files to a new server so there were only 2 files, but after attach there were 4 more files? And what is their creation/modified date in OS?

Comment: The title says "after restoring", the text inside says "detach/attach", so what did you use, backup/restore or detach/attach?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly possible that a database grow after a migration. It is not advisable to do that often but you could shrink datatase to release the free space.